# Toggle button with blade components and alpine.js

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I'm trying to create my own toggle component. This component should just behave like a normal `<input type="checkbox" >`. So far I've created the following:

toggle.blade.php

```
@props([
    'id' => 1
])

<div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div {{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('class')->merge(['class' => 'relative rounded-full transition duration-200 ease-linear' ]) }}
        :class="[ $refs.toggle{{ $id }}.checked ? 'bg-green-400' : 'bg-gray-400' ]">
        <label for="toggle{{ $id }}"
            class="absolute left-0 bg-white border-2 mb-2 w-1/2 h-full rounded-full transition transform duration-100 ease-linear cursor-pointer"
            :class="[ $refs.toggle{{ $id }}.checked ? 'translate-x-full border-green-400' : 'translate-x-0 border-gray-400' ]"></label>
        <input x-ref="toggle{{ $id }}" type="checkbox" id="toggle{{ $id }}" class="appearance-none w-full h-full active:outline-none focus:outline-none"
            {{ $attributes }} x-init="console.log('test')" />
    </div>
</div>
```

How I call it:

```
<div>
  <x-inputs.toggle class="w-8 h-4" value="{{ $permission['id'] }}" 
    id="{{ $permission['id'] }}" x-model="permissions" /> <-- this one
  <input class="form-checkbox" value="{{ $permission['id'] }}" type="checkbox" x-model="permissions">
</div>
```

I want to be able to put an x-model on my component. So that I can use the normal two-way binding from a checkbox input.

The code above works, but because the ref (input) is later initialized than the `$refs` calls. Causing the wrong classes in the toggle, until one of the checkboxes/toggles is pressed (refs updated), see image:

[image: Upload permission checkboxes/toggles]

Normally, I would just give the component an x-data and check if toggled, etc. But then I can't use the x-model because the model doesn't exist in the x-data property of the component.

What I also tried is passing the value of the `x-model` in the class property like: `:class="[ {{ $attirubtes->whereStartsWith('x-model')->first() ? ... : ... ]"`. But this doesn't work either, because I pass an array to the x-model checkbox, where alpine.js does some fancy things and handles it correctly.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're nearly there. It's a little tricky without seeing your `x-data` but using the `refs` you're kind of going the long way round instead of using the reactivity that's built in, which is why you're seeing a delayed update.

I think you've said that your `permissions` variable is an array. If so you can get the alpine variable name and the value of your checkbox in the blade component and use those to determine if the toggle should be checked.

**In the blade component**

```
<?php
    // Here we get the name of your alpine variable and the
    // value for the toggle
    $alpineVar = $attributes->whereStartsWith('x-model')->first();
    $value = $attributes->whereStartsWith('value')->first();
    
    // Here we build the javascript expression used to check
    // our permissions array for the toggle value
    $expression = "$alpineVar.includes('$value')";
?>

<div class="flex justify-center items-center">
    <div 
    {{ $attributes->whereStartsWith('class')->merge(['class' => 'relative rounded-full transition duration-200 ease-linear' ]) }}
    :class="[
        {{ $expression }} ? 'bg-green-400' : 'bg-gray-400'
    ]">
        <label 
        for="toggle{{ $id }}"
        class="absolute left-0 bg-white border-2 mb-2 w-1/2 h-full rounded-full transition transform duration-100 ease-linear cursor-pointer"
        :class="[
            {{ $expression }} ? 'translate-x-full border-green-400' : 'translate-x-0 border-gray-400'
        ]"></label>
        <input id="toggle{{ $id }}" type="checkbox" class="appearance-none w-full h-full active:outline-none focus:outline-none" {{ $attributes }} />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here we get the name of the AlpineJs instance variable from your `x-model` attribute and use that to check for the `value` in the array so we can toggle between the classes on the `div` and `label` elements.

**In the page**

```
<div 
x-data="{
    permissions: ['view','read','create']
}">
    <x-inputs.toggle class="w-8 h-4" value="view" x-model="permissions" />
</div>
```

I'm obviously using an example `x-data` instance here, so customise that to your needs. Here we pass in a value of `view` found in the `permissions` object and bound in with x-model to give us the reactivity we need.

I hope that all makes sense and answers your question